# Sending email using a Transactional Email Template with SendGrid

Tags: email, meteor, sendgrid

How can I send email using a transactional email template with SendGrid.

I am using the `email` package from meteorjs and I am able to send simple emails through

```
  Email.send({
    from: "myemail@gmail.com",
    to: "somebodyelses.email@gmail.com",
    subject: "A sample subject",
    text: "Here is some text."
  });
```

I can't find meteorjs packages either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you configured the email package with the correct host name and credentials? You can [see an example on the SendGrid blog](https://sendgrid.com/blog/send-email-meteor-sendgrid/). Once you've got the server configured properly and you can send simple emails, then you can add to `Email.headers` an X-SMTPAPI header. Then you can [use transactional templates via the X-SMTPAPI header](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Transactional_Templates/smtpapi.html).

It will look something like this:

```
Email.send({
  from: "myemail@gmail.com",
  to: "somebodyelses.email@gmail.com",
  subject: "A sample subject",
  text: "Here is some text.",
  headers: {"X-SMTPAPI": '{
      "filters": {
        "templates": {
          "settings": {
            "enable": 1,
            "template_id": "5997fcf6-2b9f-484d-acd5-7e9a99f0dc1f"
          }
        }
      }
    }'
  }
});
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Adding the `headers` did the trick. However, I am receiving everything in plaintext. Meaning the images are gone, and the text are not formatted. Any clue?

Comment: Ok got it to work by  adding `"Content-Type" : "text/html"` to `headers`.

Comment: I think this is because your `html` parameter is not set in the `Email.send` call. Setting it to something random worked for me as well.

Comment: @MarkPazon Its sending only simple text email for me even after adding "Content-Type" : "text/html" . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47217847/trigger-sendgrid-template-email-using-meteor 
Any help?