# Trigger sendgrid template email using meteor

Tags: meteor, sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

I am using sendgrid to send an email. I want to send template as an email to users. Below code is just sending the simple text based email instead of defining the headers part and using the template id.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Email.send({
        from: "from@mailinator.com",
        to: "abc@mail.com",
        subject: "Subject",
        text: "Here is some text",
        headers: {"X-SMTPAPI": {
            "filters" : {
                "template" : {
                    "settings" : {
                        "enable" : 1,
                        "Content-Type" : "text/html",
                        "template_id": "3fca3640-b47a-4f65-8693-1ba705b9e70e"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }



    });
}
```

Your help will highly be appreciated.

Best

Comment: From the sendgrid docs it looks like you are doing everything correctly. Ditto from the Meteor side. Do the headers come through in the email?

Comment: Have you tried stringifying your `X-SMTPAPI` header?

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

To send SendGrid transactional templates you have different options

### 1) Via the SendGrid SMPT API

In this case we can use Meteor email package (as you were trying).

To add meteor email package we need to type in the sell:

```
meteor add email
```

In this case, according to [SendGrid docs](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Transactional_Templates/smtpapi.html#-Text-or-HTML-Templates):

> The `text` property is substituted into the ***<%body%>*** of the text template and `html` is substituted into the ***<%body%>*** of the HTML template. If the `text` property is present, but not `html`, then the resulting email will only contain the text version of the template, not the HTML version.

So in your code you need to provide `http` property too, that's all.

This could be your **server code**:

```
// Send via the SendGrid SMTP API, using meteor email package
Email.send({
  from: Meteor.settings.sendgrid.sender_email,
  to: userEmail,
  subject: "your template subject here",
  text: "template plain text here",
  html: "template body content here",
  headers: {
    'X-SMTPAPI': {
      "filters": {
        "templates": {
          "settings": {
            "enable": 1,
            "template_id": 'c040acdc-f938-422a-bf67-044f85f5aa03'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

### 2) Via the SendGrid Web API v3

You can use `meteor http` package to use SendGrid Web API v3 ([here docs](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Transactional_Templates/templates.html)). In this case we can use the Meteor http package.

To add Meteor http package type in the shell:

```
meteor add http
```

Then in your **server code** you can use

```js
// Send via the SendGrid Web API v3, using meteor http package
var endpoint, options, result;

endpoint = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send';

options = {
  headers: {
    "Authorization": `Bearer ${Meteor.settings.sendgrid.api_key}`,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  data: {
    personalizations: [
      {
        to: [
          {
            email: userEmail
          }
        ],
        subject: 'the template subject'
      }
    ],
    from: {
      email: Meteor.settings.sendgrid.sender_email
    },
    content: [
      {
        type: "text/html",
        value: "your body content here"
      }
    ],
    template_id: 'c040acdc-f938-422a-bf67-044f85f5aa03'
  }
};

result = HTTP.post(endpoint, options);
```